# How to handle react router empty url params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a url with structure like the following

```
<Route path="/product-:category-:subcategory-:variableOne-:variableTwo" component={Product} />
```

If someone goes to the url with all variabbles values passed, then it works fine, but how to setup if someone dont pass the variable then its gives a blank value

This works fine:

```
/product-health-fitness-happy-women
```

But if someone goes to this, it shows empty page the default handler:

```
/product--fitness-happy-women
/product-clothes--happy-women
```

How to handle this with empty values of parameter

Comment: maybe instead of route parameters use query parameters that way you can pass in as many or as little as you need

Comment: this seems like a fragile uri design, if you are stuck with it then you could use defaults such as `any` for undefined params and handle them witthin your route so that you can maintain the structure e.g. `/product-any-fitness-happy-women`

Comment: @RobertTerrell I want the url structure to be seo friendly, so this way, is required

Comment: @AMacdonald so can you suggest any other uri design which is seo friendly as well as maintains the uri structure, so that I don't have to pass any values like [any, all, etc.]

Comment: in that case you would have to pass in the exact amount of route parameters that your route expects I believe regardless if they exist or not so maybe pass in null values etc if you aren't passing in a health param

Comment: @RobertTerrell thanks I am going this way only for now